# How to choose landing page after user logs in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering when a user logs in using the login control for ASP.NET, how do we choose where the user goes after?  Do we configure this in the web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you go where the user asked to go.

What usually happens is that the user requests to go to a page which requires that he be authenticated. If he's not authenticated, he gets redirected to the login page. That page accepts username and password, and gets him authenticated. It then redirects him to the page he originally requested.

Users may get annoyed with you if they requested to go to page "A" and you send them to page "B".

If the user didn't request a particular page, then he will usually go to Default.aspx. At that point, you might choose a landing page for the user, in whatever manner you like, and redirect to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FormsAuthentication** *DefaultUrl* property or forced redirect user with *Response.Redirect(...)* after he logged in.
Or just simply allow user continue with his initial request.